# jQuery animate bottom div

Tags: jquery

I try to move a specific `div` using jQuery `animate`. However, It does not work for div, but it works for `img`.
Here's my code (it doesn't work):

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickme').hover(function() {
      $('#lol').animate({
        bottom: '+=100',
        left: '+=100'
      }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="lol" style="width: 500px; border: 1px solid #000; display: block;">aaaaaa</div>
</body>
```

But this one, will work:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickme').hover(function() {
      $('#book').animate({
        bottom: '+=100',
        left: '+=100'
      }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="http://img.labnol.org/images/2008/03/firefox-google-logo.jpg" alt="" width="266" height="113"
  style="position: relative; left: 10px;" />

</body>
```

Comment: `animate()` will only work if your element is positioned using : `position:absolute` or `position:relative`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make position of the div absolute or relative;

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position: relative` on your DIV.

The default is `static` which doesn't let you manipulate the `top` and `left` properties.

Answer (score 0):

your div should be position either absolute or relative.
If you do not want to alter it's css positioning, you can try to animate it using the css margin prop